# How to prove that the following composition of mappings from Riemann sphere to Riemann sphere is a möbius transformation?

Tags: riemann-surfaces, mobius-transformation

I’m reading O.Foster’s «Lectures on Riemann surfaces» and trying to solve the edited version of exercise 1.3. [O. Foster’s «Lectures on Riemann surfaces»](https://staff.math.su.se/shapiro/UIUC/Foster.pdf) Instead of proving that the mapping is biholomorphic I need to prove that it is a Möbius transformation.

As far as I understand, I need to manually check if it’s true for generators of $SO_{3}$.

I’ve written the stereographic projection $\sigma : S^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^1$ as $(s, u, t) \mapsto [s + it: 1 - u]$ and the reverse one as $\sigma^{-1}: \mathbb{C}P^1 \mapsto S^2$, $[x : y] \mapsto (2Re(x\bar{y})/(|x|^2 + |y|^2), 2Im(x\bar{y})/(|x|^2 + |y|^2), (|x|^2 - |y|^2)/(|x|^2 + |y|^2))$.

But when I use this mapping with, for example,$$ \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$$ and get, that $[x : y] \mapsto (2Im(x\bar{y})/(|x|^2 + |y|^2) + i*(|x|^2 - |y|^2)/(|x|^2 + |y|^2), 1 - 2Re(x\bar{y})/(|x|^2 + |y|^2))$.

As I see, I’ve chosen inefficient way to prove that this is a möbius transformation.

Comment: Do you already know that conformal self-maps of the Riemann sphere are Moebius?

Comment: @MoisheKohan No, I do not.

Comment: Then, my suggestion you prove this first (it is not hard, reduce to the case of confirmal maps fixing infinity) instead of doing uninformative brute-force calculations. Then prove that the stereographic projection is conformal.

Comment: @MoisheKohan can I do this with basic knowledge of complex analysis?

Comment: Absolutely! Can you prove that an entire function without an essential singularity at infinity is polynomial?

Comment: @MoisheKohan is it the same as proving that if an entire function has a pole at infinity then it is a polynomial?

Comment: Of course......

Comment: @MoisheKohan then I can

Comment: @MoisheKohan, I’ve proven that conformal self-maps of the Riemann sphere are Möbius, but I don’t know how I can show that the given composition is conformal(since it’s not just a stereographic map). Am I missing something?

Comment: Rotation of the sphere is clearly conformal. Now you compose three conformal maps.

Comment: @MoisheKohan, makes sense. And can I prove the fact that the stereographic projection is conformal geometrically or should I do it using some statements equating conformity with holomorphy under certain conditions? (I know how to prove that stereographic projection from $S^2 \ {N}$ to $C$ is conformal geometrically, but it's not quite the same(?))

Comment: The proof that I know uses the fact that it is a restriction of a Moebius transformation of the 3-space. But you should be able to prove conformality by computing the derivative

Comment: @MoisheKohan, and how are conformality and the derivative related?

Comment: How do you prove that a smooth map preserves angles?

Comment: @MoisheKohan, I’ve thought about it a bit. Is it true that to prove that the stereographic projection is conformal I need to calculate a Jacobian matrix and check that it is a scaled multiple of a rotation matrix?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4534283/stereographic-projections-preserve-angles